# Running a Win32 app written in NASM results in 'This app cant run on your pc' error

Tags: assembly, x86, mingw, nasm, ld

I am starting to learn x86 assembly on Windows. I am learning 32 bit x86 assembly. I use `nasm` and `ld` in order to compile my programs. I use a `mingw32-make` makefile as my build system. I am assuming `ld` came included with MinGW, but I am not sure of that. All I know is that it was already on my computer.

I wanted to compile a very simple program just to make sure everything was working and of course, it wasn't. When running my executable, a giant blue box came up and said 'This app cant run on your pc' and after closing the notification, the words `Access is denied` printed out onto my terminal.

This is my program:

```
global _main

_main:
  mov eax, 1
  ret
```

And this is my makefile:

```
main: learn.asm
    nasm -f win32 learn.asm -o learn.o
    ld learn.o -o learn.exe
```

Could someone help me fix this?

Comment: Are you sure it isn't just crashing, as it should? You need to terminate the program. On windows, I believe you can simply `ret`.

Comment: Could you provide code as an answer?

Comment: Just stick a `ret` after `mov eax, 1`.

Comment: @Jester doesnt work :(

Comment: Does your environment have the `file` command? What does it say if you run `file learn.exe`?

Comment: @Jester when I try running 'file learn.exe' in the command line, it doesnt work. This is the output: "'file' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."

Comment: I am **unsure** if directly using _start is okie dokie with windows, I assume you will have to rename your function to _main and let ld link the _start to it

Comment: @Expolarity doesn't work... maybe I should try reinstalling nasm. could you provide the link to the download page?

Comment: FWIW, `_start` worked with `wine`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Originally your question asked about using `_start` as an entry point. The way you were linking didn't include the *C* runtime.

With some versions of Windows you may get the error `This app cant run on your pc` when linking with MinGW LD if there is no `.rdata` (read only data) section under some circumstances. One circumstance appears to be an executable with an `.idata` section ([import directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/debug/pe-format?redirectedfrom=MSDN)) not referenced by the header and doesn't contain an `.rdata` section. This appears to be the case when the MinGW LD linker creates the executable from your code when not using a *C* runtime. To fix the problem add an `.rdata` section with at least one byte of data. This should work:

```
global _start

section .rdata
db 0

section .text
_start:
    mov eax, 1
    ret
```

You also need to place your code in the `.text` section or you may encounter other problems. You can then assemble and link with:

```
nasm -fwin32 learn.asm -o learn.obj
ld -o learn.obj -o learn.exe
```

If you want to use `_main` and intend to use the *C* runtime then you don't need to create an `.rdata` section, however you would assemble and link with:

```
nasm -fwin32 learn.asm -o learn.obj
gcc -m32 learn.obj -o learn.exe
```

---

### My Recommendation for Linking

Alternatively you can use a different linker than LD. [GoLink](http://www.godevtool.com/) in particular should generate an executable from the code you were using. You can create a Win32 console application with a `_start` entry point this way:

```
nasm -fwin32 learn.asm -o learn.obj
golink /console /entry _start learn.obj
```

GoLink will produce an executable with proper headers and sections that Windows should have no problem running without the need to add an `.rdata` section.

If you have MSVC/C++ installed you can also use the [Microsoft linker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/linking?view=msvc-160):

```
nasm -fwin32 learn.asm -o learn.obj
link learn.obj /entry:start /subsystem:console
```

Comment: The background seems to be the ".idata" section (which need not to be named ".idata", by the way): If `ld` is used in the way the OP did it, no start-up code is used, so the entry point is `_main` (or `_start`, if the function is named this way). Because a program must call the OS (at least for `exit`ing) and the only reliable (and allowed) possibility to call the Windows Kernel is using DLLs, a program must use DLLs. Returning using `ret` from the entry-point code is neither allowed in Windows nor in Linux.

Comment: @MartinRosenau : A Win32 process can terminate if the main thread returns with a `ret` if and only if the main thread is the one and only thread active.

Comment: If a Windows loader ever happened to create more than one thread then it would be possible that the `ret` would not result in the process exiting. General rule of thumb though to avoid that issue is to call ExitProcess. I'm not one to use `ret` like this myself.

Comment: Interesting. However, I observed that a lot of Windows versions refused loading an executable file if no DLL files were listed in the imports section. Windows Vista or Windows 7 (I'm not sure) simply does nothing if an EXE file does not contain any imports: The code is not executed but the program returns at once. You can verify that by programming an endless loop or some code that causes an exception. I can imagine that Windows 10 prints the error message reported in the question instead of "silently" doing nothing.