# Linking assembly with ld in Windows

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, ld

I have this "Hello world!" program written in assembly (NASM syntax):

```
; hello.asm
global _start

extern GetStdHandle
extern WriteFile

section .text
_start:
    push dword -11
    call GetStdHandle
    sub esp, 4
    mov ebx, esp
    push dword 0
    push ebx
    push message_length
    push message
    push eax
    call WriteFile
    add esp, 4
    xor eax, eax
    ret

section .data
    message: db `Hello world!\r\n`
    message_length equ $ - message
```

I tried linking the object file with MinGW's `ld` but I couldn't get it to work:

```
nasm -f win32 hello.asm -o hello.obj
ld -mi386pe hello.obj -o hello.exe -lkernel32
```

The output of `ld` is:

```
ld: cannot find -lkernel32
```

Trying to link the object file with GoLink results in a success:

```
nasm -f win32 hello.asm -o hello.obj
golink /entry _start /console hello.obj -o hello.exe kernel32.dll
```

The output of GoLink is:

```
GoLink.Exe Version 1.0.3.0  Copyright Jeremy Gordon 2002-2018   info@goprog.com
Output file: hello.exe
Format: Win32   Size: 2,048 bytes
```

And the program runs fine:

```
> hello
Hello world!

>
```

How do I link an object file using `ld` under Windows? Please note that I don't want to link to the CRT, since I'm not using it.

Here are my failed attempts, and their outputs:

```
> ld -mi386pe hello.obj -o hello.exe -lkernel32
ld: cannot find -lkernel32

> ld -mi386pe hello.obj -o hello.exe -LC:\Windows\System32 -lkernel32
ld: skipping incompatible C:\Windows\System32/kernel32.dll when searching for -lkernel32
ld: skipping incompatible C:\Windows\System32/kernel32.dll when searching for -lkernel32
ld: cannot find -lkernel32

> ld -mi386pe hello.obj -o hello.exe -LC:\Windows\SysWOW64 -lkernel32
ld: hello.obj:hello.asm:(.text+0x3): undefined reference to `GetStdHandle'
ld: hello.obj:hello.asm:(.text+0x18): undefined reference to `WriteFile'
```

Also, output if I decorate the names as `_GetStdHandle@4` and `_WriteFile@20`:

```
> ld -mi386pe hello.obj -o hello.exe -LC:\Windows\SysWOW64 -lkernel32
ld: warning: resolving _GetStdHandle@4 by linking to _GetStdHandle
Use --enable-stdcall-fixup to disable these warnings
Use --disable-stdcall-fixup to disable these fixups
ld: warning: resolving _WriteFile@20 by linking to _WriteFile
> hello
Access is denied.
> rem This also gives a popup window which says "This app can't run on your PC"

> ld -mi386pe hello.obj -o hello.exe -LC:\Windows\SysWOW64 --disable-stdcall-fixup -lkernel32
ld: hello.obj:hello.asm:(.text+0x3): undefined reference to `GetStdHandle@4'
ld: hello.obj:hello.asm:(.text+0x18): undefined reference to `WriteFile@20'

> ld -mi386pe hello.obj -o hello.exe -LC:\Windows\SysWOW64 --enable-stdcall-fixup -lkernel32
> hello
Access is denied.
```

Also, output if I decorate the names as `_GetStdHandle` and `_WriteFile`:

```
> ld -mi386pe hello.obj -o hello.exe -LC:\Windows\SysWOW64 -lkernel32
> hello
Access is denied.
> rem It doesn't change if I add --enable-stdcall-fixup or --disable-stdcall-fixup
```

Platform details:

- Windows 10 x64
- nasm 2.14rc15
- ld 2.32
- gcc 9.2.0
- golink 1.0.3.0

Comment: Try passing an appropriate `-L` operand referring to the directory in which `kernel32.dll` is located.

Comment: I did and it succeeds in linking. However, the output `hello.exe` gives a popup `This app can't run on your PC` and the command prompt says "Access is denied.". I am using the `lib32` folder as a search directory (`ld` is in the `bin` folder).

Comment: I misread your comment a bit. Should I give `ld` the folder to the `libkernel32.a` or to the actual `kernel32.dll` (C:\Windows\SysWOW64)?

Comment: I think the later but I don't really know for sure.  Try experimenting!

Comment: @fuz Tried both. Both say that the symbols `GetStdHandle` and `WriteFile` cannot be resolved. I tried decorating the names, and now it says `GetStdHandle@4` and `WriteFile@20` can't be resolved.

Comment: Very strange.  Unfortunatly I have no idea about how this exactly works, so you might have to wait for someone else.

Comment: @DavidWohlferd Does `ld` always expect to link with the C runtime? I thought `ld` is just a linker, and all the C stuff is left to `gcc`.

Comment: Maybe this answer may be relevant or helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/65441421/3857942

Comment: @MichaelPetch Thank you, it worked! Changing the `.data` to `.rdata` did the trick (since the message is a constant anyway). Can this behavior of `ld` be considered a bug, though?

Comment: I consider it a bug in some versions of LD. There are other versions of LD that don't exhibit this behaviour from what I remember. The LD in the CYGWIN compiler being one of them as I recall.